# Any platforms for articles/essay correction?

Tags: discussion

There are numerous platforms that teach english, but are there any for articles/essay correction, because where learning is necessary , practicing is also important. Is there any online websites which you could send your material for correction to?

Comment: How much are you prepared to pay? Free advice is often worth no more than you paid for it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Usually less.

Comment: I see Lang-8 mentioned a lot in comments. (This is not a recommendation, merely an observation.)